# save generated pdf on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

I'm generating pdf from view using `ROTATIVA`

```
    public ActionResult StandartPDF()
    {
        var makeCvSession = Session["makeCV"];
        var something = new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("StandartPDF", makeCvSession) { FileName = "cv.pdf" };
        return something;

    }
```

using that code user can download it. But at first I want to it on server. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved that using `SaveOnServerPath` property in `Rotativa` class

```
public ActionResult StandartPDF()
    {

        var makeCvSession = Session["makeCV"];

        var root = Server.MapPath("~/PDF/");
        var pdfname = String.Format("{0}.pdf", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        var path = Path.Combine(root, pdfname);
        path = Path.GetFullPath(path);

        var something = new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("StandartPDF", makeCvSession) { FileName = "cv.pdf", SaveOnServerPath = path };
        return something;

    }
```